# Radius, Center, and Plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do you determine the radius, center, and the plane containing the circle $r(t)=7i+(12cos(t))j+(12sin(t))k?$  The way I tried it is using just the basic approach:
$$7^2+(12cos(t))^2=12sin(t))^2$$ $$ 49 + 144cos^2t=144sin^2t$$
$$144cos^2t-144sin^2t=-49$$
$$144sin^2t-144cos^2t=49$$
$$144(cos^2t-sin^2t)=49$$
$$144cos(2t)=49$$
which yields a radius of 144 but surely this can't be correct since this is not a circle! Any detailed help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\textbf{r}(t)=\langle 7,12\cos(t),12\sin(t) \rangle$, so the $x$'s component is being fixed for every $t$ and so it makes the vector function living in the plane $x=7$. Now consider you are moving on $x=7$. So, you are lost the $x$ component. This means that you know just $y(t)=12\cos(t),~~z(t)=12\sin(t)$. What does this mean? Indeed $y^2+z^2=144$, that is a circle with center $(7,0,0)$ and radii $R=12$.

[image]

Comment: $\Large \color{blue}{+_+^+}$

Comment: Hello!, Amy. Wish you very clean moments ahead. :)

Comment: @BabakS. That's really clever! What program did you use? Also could you by any change tell me the code because I am just getting into computational mathematics using Sage and I got to say, that is a really attractive picture even if it is for a simple function!

Comment: @EamesCobb: It is a kind of you. Thanks. :) I used Maple 16 for that. The main code for this problem is "spacecurve". You can search the real complete code in Maple's help. For example: spacecurve([cos(t), sin(t), 5], t = 0 .. 4*Pi, color = red) makes aa unit circle in $\mathbb R^3$ lying on $z=5$.

Answer (score 1):

Given your notation, it should be clear that this is a circle of radius $12$ within the plane $x=7$, centered on the $x$ axis.  This may be read right from the vector expression given without any further operations being performed.